# mpich2 and mpi4py problems with scatter and getter example

Tags: python, mpi, mpich

I'm trying to run a scatter and gatter example using python but having problems. To make sure that my cluster is working well, I tried a helloworld:

```
$ cat /var/nfs/helloworld.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Parallel Hello World
"""

from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

sys.stdout.write( "Hello, World! I am process %d of %d on %s.\n" % (rank, size, name))
```

so looks my machinefile:

```
$ cat /var/nfs/machinefile 
node1:8
node2:8
desktop01:8
```

so looks the output from `lscpu -p` for the tree nodes

```
$ lscpu -p
# The following is the parsable format, which can be fed to other
# programs. Each different item in every column has an unique ID
# starting from zero.
# CPU,Core,Socket,Node,,L1d,L1i,L2,L3
0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,,1,1,1,0
2,2,0,0,,2,2,2,0
3,3,0,0,,3,3,3,0
4,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0
5,1,0,0,,1,1,1,0
6,2,0,0,,2,2,2,0
7,3,0,0,,3,3,3,0
```

and it runs as expected with the following command

```
$ mpiexec.hydra  -np 24  --machinefile /var/nfs/machinefile python /var/nfs/helloworld.py 
Hello, World! I am process 22 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 19 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 20 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 18 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 23 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 16 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 21 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 17 of 24 on desktop01.
Hello, World! I am process 5 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 15 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 13 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 11 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 8 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 6 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 10 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 12 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 14 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 9 of 24 on node2.
Hello, World! I am process 7 of 24 on node1.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 24 on node1.

$
```

with that I assume my cluster is working.

So now I tried the a demo, that comes with mpi4py (2.0.0) and I'm using python 3, and all nodes are Linux, running mpich2 (3.1.2)

```
$ cat /var/nfs/3.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

print("-"*78)
print(" Running on %d cores" % comm.size)
print("-"*78)

my_N = 4
N = my_N * comm.size

if comm.rank == 0:
    A = np.arange(N, dtype=np.float64)
else:
    A = np.empty(N, dtype=np.float64)

my_A = np.empty(my_N, dtype=np.float64)

# Scatter data into my_A arrays
comm.Scatter( [A, MPI.DOUBLE], [my_A, MPI.DOUBLE] )

print("After Scatter:")
for r in range(comm.size):
    if comm.rank == r:
        print("[%d] %s" % (comm.rank, my_A))
    comm.Barrier()

# Everybody is multiplying by 2
my_A *= 2

# Allgather data into A again
comm.Allgather( [my_A, MPI.DOUBLE], [A, MPI.DOUBLE] )

print("After Allgather:")
for r in range(comm.size):
    if comm.rank == r:
        print("[%d] %s" % (comm.rank, A))
    comm.Barrier()
```

trying to run it, It fails:

```
$ mpiexec.hydra  -np 24   --machinefile /var/nfs/machinefile /var/nfs/3.py 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[0] [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 24 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/nfs/3.py", line 32, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 568, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:97474)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(428).......: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(335)..: Failure during collective
MPIR_Barrier_impl(328)..: 
MPIR_Barrier(292).......: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(149).: 
barrier_smp_intra(109)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_impl(1458)...: 
MPIR_Bcast(1482)........: 
MPIR_Bcast_intra(1291)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_binomial(309): Failure during collective
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/nfs/3.py", line 32, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 568, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:97474)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(428).......: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(335)..: Failure during collective
MPIR_Barrier_impl(328)..: 
MPIR_Barrier(292).......: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(149).: 
barrier_smp_intra(109)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_impl(1458)...: 
MPIR_Bcast(1482)........: 
MPIR_Bcast_intra(1291)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_binomial(309): Failure during collective
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/nfs/3.py", line 32, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 568, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:97474)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(428).......: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(335)..: Failure during collective
MPIR_Barrier_impl(328)..: 
MPIR_Barrier(292).......: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(149).: 
barrier_smp_intra(109)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_impl(1458)...: 
MPIR_Bcast(1482)........: 
MPIR_Bcast_intra(1291)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_binomial(309): Failure during collective
*** stack smashing detected ***: python3 terminated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/nfs/3.py", line 32, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 568, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:97474)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(428).......: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(335)..: Failure during collective
MPIR_Barrier_impl(328)..: 
MPIR_Barrier(292).......: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(149).: 
barrier_smp_intra(109)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_impl(1458)...: 
MPIR_Bcast(1482)........: 
MPIR_Bcast_intra(1291)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_binomial(309): Failure during collective
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/nfs/3.py", line 32, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 568, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:97474)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(428).......: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Barrier_impl(335)..: Failure during collective
MPIR_Barrier_impl(328)..: 
MPIR_Barrier(292).......: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra(149).: 
barrier_smp_intra(109)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_impl(1458)...: 
MPIR_Bcast(1482)........: 
MPIR_Bcast_intra(1291)..: 
MPIR_Bcast_binomial(309): Failure during collective

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 6022 RUNNING AT node1
=   EXIT CODE: 6
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
[proxy:0:2@desktop01] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:885): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:2@desktop01] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:2@desktop01] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@desktop01] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@desktop01] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@desktop01] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:218): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@desktop01] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:344): process manager error waiting for completion
```

However, asking to run everything in one node, runs well as well:

```
$ mpiexec.hydra  -np 8   --machinefile /var/nfs/machinefile /var/nfs/3.py 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[0] [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
After Allgather:
[0] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[1] [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
After Allgather:
[1] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[2] [  8.   9.  10.  11.]
After Allgather:
[2] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[3] [ 12.  13.  14.  15.]
After Allgather:
[3] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[4] [ 16.  17.  18.  19.]
After Allgather:
[4] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[5] [ 20.  21.  22.  23.]
After Allgather:
[5] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[6] [ 24.  25.  26.  27.]
After Allgather:
[6] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Running on 8 cores
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After Scatter:
[7] [ 28.  29.  30.  31.]
After Allgather:
[7] [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.
  60.  62.]

$
```

what I'm doing wrong? Is there any mismatch between the amount of data that I should send to scatter/gatter methods? Is that a known problem from mpich2? I'm quite sure that it used to work, using openmpi + python 2 - however I cannot test it, now.

Comment: How sure are you that all three nodes are definitely running (only) mpich?  Are you certain that one of them isn't defaulting to an openmpi installation?

Comment: I re-flashed the operating system (ubuntu) on all nodes and installed mpich from the source code.. all of nodes runs the same version. beside it, I'm calling hydra on the master node, and the mpi proxy - running on the other nods -  control the version running.. so it's impossible to mix the versions...

Comment: Check the network interfaces on all nodes. Make sure that no firewall is blocking TCP/IP communication between them. Make sure there are no network interfaces with matching network addresses but not providing actual connectivity (e.g. virtual bridges). The Hello World example **does not** prove that MPI is working as it involves no communication (only I/O redirection)

Comment: interesting.. firewall is disabled in all machines, however I will check it again. The three nodes are connected in the same switch, no firewall.. however I will investigate it.

Comment: no firewall between the nodes

Comment: @HristoIliev do you know if there is a *self-test* mechanism in the MPI implementations that could be used in such a case? From my experience those kinds of problems can even be caused very subtle infiniband issues that are incredibly difficult to debug.

Comment: @Zulan, usually, several calls to `MPI_Alltoallv` one after another should be enough to lazy-open all possible internode connections. Or an any-to-any message passing scheme with `MPI_Ssend`. It should be executed more than once to cover the case when the MPI library tries to load-balance over more than one network interfaces (as e.g. Open MPI does)